# Give an example of three different groups with eight elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Give an example of three different groups with eight elements. Why are the groups different?

One particular answer that I found was the groups $\mathbb{Z}_8$, $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times\mathbb{Z}_2$, and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Would someone be able to explain this answer easily so I can understand? Feel free to give an a different answer if you think you have a better one or you believe this one is wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Yes, those three groups will work. To see why they're different, recall that isomorphisms will preserve the number of elements of a particular order. Try figuring out the number of elements of each order in each group.

Comment: Well from the answer, it said that $Z_8$ has an element of order 8 that the others don't have. However, I'm not quite sure what that means?

Comment: For each of the $3$ groups, try explicitly listing out each of its $8$ elements and computing each of their orders.

Comment: That's what confuses me. How do you compute the order?

Comment: The order of an element is the minimum number of copies of that element that you need to apply the group operation to until you get the identity. For example, consider the element $6 \in Z_8$. Recall that the identity here is $0$, and the operation is addition modulo $8$. Now $6 + 6 = 4$, so the order of $6$ is not $2$. Adding $6$ again gives us $2$, so the order of $6$ is not $3$. Adding $6$ yet again gives us $0$, so the order of $6$ must be $4$.

Comment: Tell me if my logic is correct here:
So then $Z_8$ = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. The highest order of any of the elements is 7, which has an order of 8. So it differs from all the others, because it is the only group with an element of order 8

Comment: @billy The elements $1,3,5,7$ have order 8, not order 7.

Comment: I apologize - typo. I meant the highest order of any of the elements is 8. But I forgot to include that 1,3,5 and 7 also have order 8

Comment: You could just notice that $1 \in Z_8$ has order $8$. Now compute the order of each element in $Z_4 \times Z_2$. You should find that none of them have order $8$.

Comment: So in the group $Z_4$ x $Z_2$, the cross product (1,2) will have the highest order of 4?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that it's not the only element of order $4$. In general, the order of $(a,b) \in Z_4 \times Z_2$ will be:
$$
\text{lcm}\left(\frac{4}{\gcd(4,a)}, \frac{2}{\gcd(2,b)}\right)
$$

Comment: Great. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it! I think I understand it a lot better now!

Answer (score 0):

There are two more, both of them non-abelian. (That is, multiplication isn't commutative.) The easy one is the group of symmetries of a square.

Comment: What would make that one different from say $Z_8$?

Comment: @billy $Z_8$ is abelian.  Abelian means that it has $a+b = b+a$ for all elements $a$ and $b$.  But if you flip over a square and then give it a quarter turn, the square ends up in a different position than if you do the quarter turn and then the flip (try it!), so you have $\operatorname{turn} + \operatorname{flip} \ne \operatorname{flip} + \operatorname{turn}$, which is different from anything in $Z_8$.

Comment: That makes sense. Is $Z_4$ x $Z_2$ also abelian?